# C# Web Form Submission with WebClient Example

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I've read all the relevant posts on Stack Overflow and have not found something that works although I'm a novice in the web request/response programming world.

Problem:
I have an existing application that captures data off a web page. Simple webclient downloads page (webclient.downloadstring(url)) that parses the html and grabs relevant data. Works great. Now, I have to grab additional data off this site, but the page that has the data is a list of information that has ASP.NET JavaScript post backs that are form submits.

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridViewSort_ctl02_LinkButton1" class="ui-btn ui-mini center noprint" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridViewSort$ctl02$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">More Info</a>
```

I have captured all the relevant input values from the initial web request form using developer tools:

```
__EVENTARGUMENT: 
   __EVENTTARGET: ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24GridViewSort%24ctl03%24LinkButton1
   __EVENTVALIDATION: tpO...
   __VIEWSTATE: bI2vX...
   __VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED: 
   __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR: 5037098B
   ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24hfTicket: 0
   ctl00%24ucheader2%24m_textBoxSearch: Search%E2%80%A6
```

and have tried to mimic the post back using WebClient.UploadData(url, data) where data is converted to ascii array of byte[] as per other examples. I have also tried to capture headers and cookies, but this is where things start to fall apart. Examples I have found are not working for me.

Has anyone who has accomplished this please provide a code example that I can start with. I have also downloaded and tried WatIn. This may work as a temporary solution, but browser availability limitations will require far too much maintenance and intervention. I really would like to figure out how to do this with a .NET solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: not working how exactly? It would help if you gave a clue as to what errors/problems you are encountering

Comment: My apologies... When I send the uploaddata request I simply get the same page back... I guess what I was asking for was a sample of something that is in a known working state. I have looked at the packets in fiddler and dev tools (chorme browser, and edge)... there is no error that I can see but the response I am looking for never appears... I'm stumped. I would buy a framework if one existed... I am capturing all the appropriate input elements, but the cookies and headers are giving me issue... Any assistance would be appreciated. I see this as a MUST moving forward...

Comment: To the user who recommended selenium... I have WatIn and it will work through a browser also, but I need a fully automated process... the Browser requirement will cause the system to require a user login and credentials (user profile)... there are workarounds, but I would like this to run as it is intended as a automated process...

Comment: so you need to submit some data and then read the response? Could be difficult with a .NET forms website - there's all sorts of security stuff to stop spoofing etc. Plus if you haven't got a browser environment (i.e. you're doing it via a webclient) there's no environment in which to easily simulate ajax etc. I don't offhand know of any way to do this easily.

Comment: Thanks for the response... I can't believe this is that difficult. Perhaps I should contact a Ukrainian hacker? After reading several posts on different yet similar issues, there is a lot going on as you said. It turns out that the cookies were sent as an asset from a subsequent sub-request... The old "security by obscurity" model... In time I could figure this out, but the project isn't that big that I have all kinds of time to waist on this effort... My workaround was WatIn! It is capturing all the data I require... Thanks for your responses...

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using Selenium to automate that action through a real browser?

Sounds real tricky doing this by manual requests, if you really wanna go this way, I suggest you use Fiddler to try to make your request look as much as the real one as possible.